# extended GridViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I have overriden the method getView of my Custom BaseAdapter to fill a Gridview with this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    if(convertView == null){            
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)getItem(position);
    } else{
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
    }


    return relativeLayout;
}
```

But all the time, i get this Exception and i dont get it why i get it...
getItem(position) should return a Rectangle which is a custom RelativeLayout.
Can you please help me?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

EDIT:

i already have a custom RelativeLayout which looks like this:

and in my getView i get one of these Rectangles which i have in an arraylist back..
isnt this right?

```
public class Rectangle extends RelativeLayout{


public Rectangle(Context context, int dnd_drag_button_while_dragging, String text) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        

    this.setLayoutParams(params);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setBackgroundResource(dnd_drag_button_while_dragging);
    image.setLayoutParams(params);

    img = dnd_drag_button_while_dragging;
    LayoutParams tParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(text); 
    textView.setLayoutParams(tParams);

    this.addView(image);
    this.addView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call getItem() to create your RelativeLayout. Instead you should inflate an XML layout or create the RelativeLayout programatically. See the [GridView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) for an example of how to programatically create the view in getView(). This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481202/268156) has an example of inflating a resource in getView().

Comment: i answer you in the mainpost with an EDIT

Comment: Don't store your constructed Rectangle objects in an array - this is not how the adapter works and will prevent the optimization that GridView does when it recycles views (that's what convertView is). As I said, you should switch the getItem() call in the getView() method to construct the Rectangle (either programatically or via inflating the xml). You will also need to change your getItem() override so it doesn't return the full view (it's supposed to just return some "data" that points to that row, such as an integer ID).